# python error on "import skimage": ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _remap

Tags: python, windows, dll, module, scikit-image

Can somebody help me with this? I am using Python 3.8 on Windows 10 and suddenly got this error with SKIMAGE module :/
What could it be? Something about C++?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "board_detection.py", line 6, in <module>
            import skimage
          File "C:\Users\joao_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
            from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
          File "C:\Users\joao_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
            from ._map_array import map_array
          File "C:\Users\joao_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\_map_array.py", line 2, in <module>
            from ._remap import _map_array
        ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _remap: the specific module could not found
```

Comment: How did you install scikit-image? It does look like it is missing compiled C/C++ modules.

Comment: @Juan I installed just like documentation says: python -m pip install -U scikit-image  (or simply pip install scikit-image). But this error isn't happening only to this lib, is happening to matplotlib too, but a different DLL

Comment: And which Python is it? (python.org, Anaconda, ...) To be honest, I really don't know — normally things fail at install time if you need to compile... =( My advice would be to try a different Python installation method, ie for Python itself.